# Call function when wxPython Notebook is changed?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've got a Python script nearly identical to that on [the wxPy Wiki](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Simple%20wx.Notebook%20Example), and I'd like to run a function in  (no indentation) every time the tab is changed. I've tried just putting `theFunction()` after the `wx.Frame.__init__...` line in the `def __init__` in each of hte three classes used by the Notebook. When I do this, the window closes immediately after closing, with no error in the terminal. What am I doing wrong? Here's what I have for each class used by the notebook:

```
class Textures(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textureslist = wx.ListBox(choices = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], id = -1, name = 'textureslist', parent = self, pos = (6, 0), size = (382, 150))
        getDivVars()
```

EDIT: The reason it was quitting was related to accidentally using App, not PySimpleApp. However, the list still doesn't update (which getDivVars() does) each time the tab is changed. I still need to do this.

Comment: I doubt App had anything to do with it. PySimpleApp is deprecated.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll didn't know it was deprecated. I changed between App and PySimpleApp, and that made the difference between running and not running.

Comment: That is very odd. wx.App(False) should be equivalent to wx.PySimpleApp()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a function called whenever the notebook page changes, bind the `EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED` event to a function or method.  Taking the 'Simple wx.Notebook Example` as a starting point, you'd add a line

```
    nb.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, self.some_method)
```

or, if you want to call a function outside of a class instead of a method,

```
    nb.Bind(wx.EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED, some_function)
```

`some_function` would need to take a single parameter, and `some_method` would need to take a single parameter in addition to `self`.

Comment: Is there something EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGED is normally bound to that binding it overwrites, or something like that? When I add this line, it causes the page to not change when clicked.

Comment: Turns out I needed EVT_NOTEBOOK_PAGE_CHANGING (changing instead of changed)